# Pasar variable por libreria arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, gcc, arm

estoy creando un nuevo sketch en Arduino, pero tengo un problema, si bien todo se compila bien sin errores, no funciona, no sé si es una librería o el sketch, para depurar me gustaría pasar una variable que cambie de valor cuando pase por cada una de las etapas de la librería y luego tomar el resultado y enviarlo por serial al pc.

Ejemplo:

libreria.h

```
void funcion1()
{
  X = 1;
}
void funcion2()
{
  X = 2;
}
void funcion3()
{
  X = 3;
}
```

Sketch1.ino

```
int X = 0;
#include "libreria.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  funcion1();
  Serial.println(X,DEC);
  funcion2();
  Serial.println(X,DEC);
  funcion3();
  Serial.println(X,DEC);
}
```

Pero sale:

```
libreria.h:3:3 error: 'X' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Podrias editar la pregunta y mostrar el codigo del sketch para entender mejor la pregunta, aprovechando te invito a lee [mcve]

Comment: ¿ Seguro que ese es el orden exacto ? ¿ Primero la declaras y después el `#include` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta porque la variable la defines en el archivo *Sketch1.ino* pero la tratas de utilizar sin mas en *libreria.h*, a pesar de que **X** es una variable global, esto no quiere decir que *libreria.h* la valla a ver, debe declarar la variable en *libreria.h* como una variable externa la cual se encuentra definida es en  *Sketch1.ino*, tu dos archivos quedarían así:

**libreria.h**

```
extern int X; //DECLARACIÓN de X como variable externa
void funcion1()
{
  X = 1;
}
void funcion2()
{
  X = 2;
}
void funcion3()
{
  X = 3;
}
```

**Sketch1.ino**

```
#include "libreria.h"

int X = 0; //DEFINICIÓN de la variable X

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  funcion1();
  Serial.println(X,DEC);
  funcion2();
  Serial.println(X,DEC);
  funcion3();
  Serial.println(X,DEC);
}
```

---

### Qué es una variable externa?

Brevemente, existe una diferencia entre *Declarar* una variable y *Definir* una variable:

- **Definición** - cuando se define una variable, se le dice al compilador que existe una variable de cierto nombre y tipo de dato, y este le asigna memoria y un valor.
- **Declaración** - cuando se declara una variable, se le informa al compilador que existe una variable con ese nombre y ese tipo de dato, pero este no necesita asignarle memoria ni valor porque eso ya se hizo en otro lugar, solo sabe que esta existe y ya.

Ahora una variable externa es una variable definida fuera del bloque de funciones o ámbito, en lenguaje C y todos sus descendientes directos como C++ y Objetive-C, heredan unas palabras reservadas llamadas **auto**, **static**, **extern**  y **register**.

Estas palabras reservadas controlan el tipo de almacenamiento de la variable, si esta no se asigna manualmente, se asignan automáticamente de pendiendo del ámbito donde se encuentre, una variable que se define dentro de una función, se asigna automáticamente como automática(auto) y se le asigna memoria cuando inicia la función y se le elimina cuando esta termina.

La palabra reservada **Extern** informa al compilador que esa variable es una *declaración* de una variable global y que en algún otro lugar se encuentra su  *definición*.